# Datatables for mutiple tables on one page having different td count each

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

applying datatable on each table using id but it only triggers for one table and give error in console.
 "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'nTf' of undefined" while i need to display it on every table .
Using class cannot be applied because each table has different td's count .

for instance i have two tables with id's table1 & table2 and calling datatable as

$('#table1').DataTable();
$('#table2').DataTable();

Please advise any help would be appreciated

my first table is

```
<table id="table1">
  <thead> 
     <tr>
       <th>No.s</th>
       <th>Title</th>
       <th>project</th>
    </tr> 
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test project</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
   <tfoot>
     <tr>
       <th colspan="3"></th>
     </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

My second table is

```
<table id="table2">
      <thead> 
         <tr>
           <th>No.s</th>
           <th>Title</th>
           <th>Task</th>
           <th>Actions</th>
        </tr> 
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test task</td>
          <td>Edit</td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
       <tfoot>
         <tr>
           <th colspan="4"></th>
         </tr>
      </tfoot>
 </table>
```

Comment: I think datatables is failing on table1 and does not continue to process. can you please show me the structure of your table1

Comment: `what does same class has to do with each table has different td's count .` ??

Comment: I want to check things like `<thead>` tag, from my experience DataTables does not work well without `THEAD`, but you can hide it if you want

Comment: @ Luthando edited my question ,please see structure of tables .                   @ozil  according to example at https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/multiple_tables.html                      when we use datatable  for mutiple tables it works only for the tables which have same count of td's and can be applied using the  both table's same class

Comment: @ waseem ahmad can you show your `java script ` code??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using class cannot be applied because each table has different td's count

There is nothing to do `when we use datatable for mutiple tables it works only for the tables which have same count of td's and can be applied using the both table's same class`
[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7v83dLmp/1/)

Comment: Thanks ozil  it works fine now i used your example  :)

Answer (score 0):

i just had this problem and it turned out to be one too many tds in the tfoot. Check your rows and columns for extras, unclosed tags etc.